# Discord4J issue: sending messages in a loop instead

Tags: java, discord4j

Below is the code I used for a test command in Discord4J

```
gateway.on(MessageCreateEvent.class)
            .map(MessageCreateEvent::getMessage)
            .filter(message -> message.getContent().contains("test"))
            .flatMap(Message::getChannel)
            .flatMap(channel -> channel.createMessage("test!"))
            .subscribe();
```

but now if you type "test" in discord, it keeps sending messages, instead of a single message like I would expect. What's the issue here? It does work with equals() and equalsignorecase(), but with all other String checking methods it goes into a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you receive a `MessageCreateEvent` for all messages you send with the bot as well. Since your message is `createMessage("test!")`, you will also receive a message where `getContent()` returns `"test!"`. This will obviously result in `"test!".contains("test")` but not `"test!".equals("test")`.

This can be prevented by checking if the message author is a bot.

```java
filter(message -> !message.getAuthor().map(User::isBot).orElse(true))
```